# is it possible to debug Camel Scala DSL on intellij

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, apache-camel

Just wondering if anybody successfully added breakpoints to an Camel Scala DSL application and ran it in debug mode.

Comment: See http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-debug-my-route.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only set a breakpoint in Scala DSL if its part of a closure or inlined processor etc, as that code is what is being executed during routing. All the other code lines for defining the routes is one-time-only.

See this page and how you can us the debugger in Camel to simulate debugging the EIPs in the routes

- http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-debug-my-route.html

Comment: Thanks Claus. Breakpoints do work inside beans and on processors. Even on the routeBuilder, but it pass on that breakpoint when code is sent to the thin scala DSL layer, to be interpreted later. To see information during routing, the easy way is through mocks and logs.